# I want to go down further into query, but not sure how

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL Table Diagram:

[image]

My query this far:

```
SELECT tblcourses.CourseStandard,
                tblcourses.CourseID,
                tblcourses.CourseRef,
                tblcourses.CourseStandard,
                tblcourses.CourseName,
                tblcourses.CourseDuration,
                tblcourses.NQFLevel,
                tblcourses.CoursePrice,
                tblcoursestartdates.StartDate
  FROM etcgroup.tblcoursestartdates tblcoursestartdates
       INNER JOIN etcgroup.tblcourses tblcourses
          ON (tblcoursestartdates.CourseID = tblcourses.CourseID)
 WHERE tblcoursestartdates.StartDate >= Now()
```

If you look at the diagram you will see I have a 3rd table. The query above works fine. It display all the data as it should.

I want to show all the courses and their respective dates excluding those that the student is already booked for. Keep in mind that there can be 20 start dates for 1 course. This is why I am only choosing dates >= Now().

I want to make sure that a student does not get double booked. Yes I can do it afterwards. Beep student already booked BUT if I can have it now show the course dates that the student already booked then great. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using DISTINCT? Can there be duplicate start dates per course you want to suppress?

Comment: Sorry. That I forgot there while I was playing around. It need not be there.

Comment: And the task is, you want above query but only for courses a student X hasn't booked yet?

Comment: Show ALL courses except those that have been booked by the student already. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Presumably you know the `StudentID` you'd like to see.  Do a left join to the bookings table and select the mismatches.

```
     SELECT tblcourses.CourseStandard,
            tblcourses.CourseID,
            tblcourses.CourseRef,
            tblcourses.CourseStandard,
            tblcourses.CourseName,
            tblcourses.CourseDuration,
            tblcourses.NQFLevel,
            tblcourses.CoursePrice,
            tblcoursestartdates.StartDate
       FROM etcgroup.tblcoursestartdates tblcoursestartdates
 INNER JOIN etcgroup.tblcourses tblcourses 
              ON tblcoursestartdates.CourseID = tblcourses.CourseID
             AND tblcoursestartdates.StartDate >= Now()
  LEFT JOIN tblbookings
              ON tblbookings.CourseId = tblcourses.CourseId
             AND tblbookings.StudentId = <<<the student ID in question >>>
      WHERE tblbookings.BookingID IS NULL
```

The trick here is the LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL pattern. It *eliminates* the rows where the ON condition of the LEFT JOIN hit, leaving only the ones where it missed.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do a left join to tblBookings on `courseID` where the `bookingID` is `null` (there are no matches).  You'll have to provide the `studentID` as a parameter to the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CourseStandard,
                c.CourseID,
                c.CourseRef,
                c.CourseStandard,
                c.CourseName,
                c.CourseDuration,
                c.NQFLevel,
                c.CoursePrice,
                d.StartDate
FROM etcgroup.tblcoursestartdates d
INNER JOIN etcgroup.tblcourses c ON d.CourseID = c.CourseID
LEFT JOIN etcgroup.tblBookings b on c.CourseID = b.CourseID and b.StudentID = @StudentID
WHERE d.StartDate >= Now() and b.bookingID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS or NOT IN to find the courses a student has already booked:

```
SELECT 
  c.CourseStandard,
  c.CourseID,
  c.CourseRef,
  c.CourseStandard,
  c.CourseName,
  c.CourseDuration,
  c.NQFLevel,
  c.CoursePrice,
  csd.StartDate
FROM etcgroup.tblcourses c
INNER JOIN etcgroup.tblcoursestartdates csd ON csd.CourseID = tblcourses.CourseID
WHERE csd.StartDate >= Now()
AND c.CourseID NOT IN
(
  SELECT CourseID
  FROM tblbookings
  WHERE StudentID = 12345
);
```